# How to mix audio file and music from the midi file in Android?

Tags: android, audio, midi

I was able to play both the audio(mp3, wav, etc) and midi music(.mid) at a time using [SoundPool Class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html). But how can i save the output(mixer of audio file + midi music) into an audio file(mp3, wav, etc.,).

Please suggest me best approach to achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no API for capturing audio output (except the `Visualizer`, but it will only give you low-quality audio intended for visualization purposes). To do what you want to achieve you'd have to handle the audio decoding, mixing and encoding within your app (i.e. not using Android APIs).